# How do I split a string and ignore the rest for all columns in pandas?

Tags: pandas, split, apply

I have a dataframe where some rows contain multiple values separated by a "&" and I'd like to keep only the first value in those rows.

example :

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1&2 | 3 |
| 3 | 5&6 |

my desired output is :

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 |

here's my code :

```
df.apply(lambda x: i[0]  for i in x.split("&"))
```

I get the follwing error :

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

How is "x" not defined?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.split("&")[0] if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

If need omit numeric columns, so processing strings or mixed strings with numbers columns:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(object).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: x.split("&")[0] if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```